# What risk analysis model shall I use if I know the areas (sources) of risk?

Tags: risk-management, risk

I know the areas of risk in a group of companies based on a Risk Breakdown System.

With what model shall I analyze them afterwards? Is FMEA good for this purpose? If yes, how should I apply it?

Comment: You may find this blog post of mine relevant and useful: [0rsk.com: Cause + Risk + Effect](https://www.yegor256.com/2019/05/14/cause-risk-effect.html)

Answer (score 1):

Most risk methods shall help the applicant to not forget any aspects. Risk management is about achieving awareness and identifying corresponding and supporting activities (IMHO).

So, I go with PMI: Perform a *qualitative risk analysis* regarding risk probability and impact using values like high, medium, and low.

Afterwards, perform a *quantitative risk analysis*, e.g. by FMEA or other tools in order to get „real“ (and provable) numbers (e.g. cost in case of risk occursnce).

Answer (score 1):

As Tob has provided, I find PMI's framework easier to apply. Depending on the complexity, and to answer your question, you can certainly apply FMEA as well. If you need a reference, you can use NASA's criteria definitions and charts (see Fig 1-2):

https://rsdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/documents/rapid-iii-documents/mar-reference/gsfc-fap-322-208-fmea-draft.pdf

It boils down to documenting and ranking:

- risks and causes of failure(s)
- occurrence and severity rankings
- mitigation factors

These will help you come up with the associated Risk Priority Number (RPN). This data, as the name suggests, will allow you to come up with mitigation/action plans based on the priority and tackle the identified risks accordingly.